# How to find the div have the particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

html:

```
 <tr> 
          <td class="last_msg" id="408"><a href="/index/408" id="408">
               <div id="div408" class="msg-div">
               <div class="msg-actions">
                    <div id="unr_msg408" class="msg-unread"></div>
               </div>
               <div style="margin-top:14px; margin-bottom: 14px; line-height: 21px;">
                  <span class="msg-sender-name">Name</span>  
                  <span class="msg-date">Date</span><br>
                </div>
                </div>
              </a>
        <span class="msg_dlt_icon"><img id="dlt408" src="/public/images/icon-delete-blue.png" class="msg_icon_dlt" onclick="return deleteMessage()"></span>                   
          </td>                       
     </tr>
```

On clicking the span with class `msg_dlt_icon`,i need to check whether the div with class  `msg-actions` have the div `<div id="unr_msg408" class="msg-unread"></div>`.

I tried the below line,

```
var unread =$(this).closest("tr").find('.msg-actions').hasClass('.msg-unread');
```

I alerted the unread variable,it always return false.

I want to find whether  `<div id="unr_msg408" class="msg-unread"></div>` is present inside `<div class="msg-actions">` .

Is it possible to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you need to first find the children of `.msg-actions`, then check whether it has the class `msg-unread`.

```
var unread =$(this).closest("tr").find('.msg-actions > div ').hasClass('msg-unread');
```

Comment: i'd explain  the ' > '   selector , I'm not too sure OP knows what that means

Answer (score 2):

you could use

```
var unread = $(this).closest('tr').find('.msg-actions .msg-unread').length;
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
.hasClass('.msg-unread')
```

is  incorrect. `hasClass` already implies that you're looking for a CSS class. You're trying to treat it as a call like `$('.msg-unread')`. Your `hasClass()` is telling jquery to literally looking for an element that looks like

```
<foo class=".msg-unread">
            ^---note this .
```

The call should be just

```
.hasClass('msg-unread')
```

WITHOUT the `.`.

Comment: @user2439275 - you realize this has to be changed, even if it doesn't fully fix your problem